# what is it called: box potential with one infinite wall

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology

The finite square well and the infinite square well problem are well known, however is there a reason that there is almost no reference to the one sided infinite square well?

> Consider a particle with mass $m$ moving in the one dimensional potential $V(x)= \infty$ for $x<0$ , $V(x) = -V_{0}$ for $0\le x \le L$; $V(x) = 0$ for $x>L$
>   i) Can you scale this problem so that all units drop out ?
>   ii) Can you find the boundstate eigenenergies and associated wavefunctions as a function of the parameter $\lambda$?
>   iii) Can you find the free eigenstates which are characterized by the eigenenergies $E\ge 0$?

I searched Griffiths Quantum Mechanics, but it didn't have any clue to how to solve this.

**Can anybody tell me the proper formal name, so I can look it up, or tell me a reason why none such does exist?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-sided infinite square well eigenfunctions are all the odd numbered eigenfunctions of the finite square well twice as wide, by reflection symmetry. The odd-parity solutions obey the boundary conditions for the infinite square well, so this is exactly the same problem as the symmetric finite square well.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I have heard this potential called the **semi-infinite square well**. The name makes sense, at least; if I were going to pick a name for it that's probably what I would choose.

In any case, whether the potential has a name or not should have no effect on your ability to solve the corresponding Schrödinger equation. :-P

Comment: Ah...now *that* takes me back to the beginning of grad school.

Answer (score 1):

In *ye olde nuclear physics* (i.e. from the time of the liquid drop model and the semi-empirical mass formula) these were often called *"hard core"* potentials. The term is not exclusive to a rectangular well, however: the defining feature is the (effectively) infinite potential at low radius.

Very useful things, too.

Comment: Surely a hard core potential means the potential is infinite near the center but finite on both sides?

Comment: @Harry Work the problem in spherical coordinates...there is no "other" side of the radial coordinate.

Comment: But isn't the spherical problem fundamentally different to the 1D problem?

Comment: @Harry: Generally the radial coordinate separates from the angular coordinates and you really do solve it (the radial part) as a one dimensional problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://chemistry.illinoisstate.edu/standard/che460/handouts/460PinHalfWell.pdf

Refer this pdf for this problem (detailed solution of this problem)

Comment: Nikhil, Welcome to Physics.SE. Can you include a summary of the links material in your answer?